# recyclerview inner join SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I Have two sqlite table One contain Fid,name,mobile where Second table contain Sid, fsid ,subject,marks. now i wanted to get data inside recyclerView which contain fid,name ,mobile ,sum(marks) , but when i enter new data from first table adpter not showing it.

here is my query:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT  id ,name ,mobile ,SUM(marks) FROM d_TB INNER JOIN d_TBL ON id = id_t ",null);
    return c;
```

here is my adapter class :

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolder holder, final int position) {
    final CrudData data_ = student.get(position);
    holder.itxt.setText(student.get(position).getId());
    holder.nametxt.setText(student.get(position).getName());
    holder.mobileTxt.setText(student.get(position).getmobile());
    holder.sum_.setText(student.get(position).getMarks());
    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemLongClickListener() {
           @Override
             public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
               Intent i = new Intent(c,EditMarks.class);
               i.putExtra("Id", players.get(position).getId());
               i.putExtra("Name", players.get(position).getName());
               c.startActivity(i);
              }
        });
```

here is my method:

```
    private void retrieve()
{
    crudData.clear();

    DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this);
    db.openDB();
    Cursor c=db.insertSab();

    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        String id=c.getString(0);
        String name=c.getString(1);
        String pos=c.getString(2);
        String sum=c.getString(3);

        CrudData p=new CrudData(id,name,pos,sum);

        crudData.add(p);
    }
    if(!(crudData.size()<1))
    {
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    db.closeDB();;
}
```

Comment: are you asking that recyclerview  is not updating after new data insertion  ?

Comment: yes , recyclerView not updating

Comment: no i am not it's not working

Answer (score 1):

in your data update method 
  call `notifyDataSetChanged();` if method is in your adapter else
   if your update method is in your activity call youradapter.`notifyDataSetChanged();`

or you can do following things  if your data is coming from some api call and getting inserted in your database

1. send a broadcast from where you insert the data into database
2. then receive the broadcast int the activity where you set your adapter
3. make a public method in your adapter to get your data i.e your cursor

   in your adapter e.g

   ```
   public void refreshData(){

         Cursor=yourdatabase.getyourMethod();

           notifyDataSetChanged();}
   ```
4. then onReceive of your broadcast call refreshData from your adapter like

   ```
         adapter.refreshData()
   ```